# Knowing one $0$ of a quadratic trin., can I determine some necessary ( or sufficient) condition regarding the second root, in terms of the first one?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, roots, quadratics

- Suppose I am given this equation : $x^2 - 12x - 28$ = 0.
- Using the rational root theorem, I find that the possible rational roots are ( if I am correct):

$$1/1, 2/1,7/1,14/,28/1$$ or their additive inverses.

- I try the number $(-2)$ and I observe it works.
- At this stage, knowing one solution of the quadratic trinomial , is there any rule allowing me to determine the second root in terms of the first, or, at least, a rule allowing me to eliminate some candidates in the list above?
- I mean, is there some general law stating a relation between the roots of a quadratic trinomial?

Comment: Sum of roots is $-(-12)$, and their product is $-28$ (Vieta formula). Also you can divide $x^2-12x-28$ by $x+2$.

Comment: Why is the sum the opposite of  coefficient $b$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Thanks for this link!

Comment: Other possible rational roots, although they don't workin this case, are 4/1, -4/1

Comment: Why is something in mathematics true? Because there’s a proof.

Comment: The reason why Vieta's law holds is very simple : Just note $$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$$ $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ are obviously the roots and the coefficients are $\ -(a+b)\ $ and $\ ab\ $

Comment: @Peter. Thanks for this explanation.